# Chef recipe fails on service resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Hi all my chef recipes have recently started breaking when I use a service resource. Whenever I try to use the service resource to start or stop a service, my chef run breaks with the following error:

```
TypeError
    ---------
    no implicit conversion of false into Array
```

For example I try to start the postfix service using the following in my recipe

```
service "postfix" do
      action [:enable, :start]
end
```

but when I run the recipe it fails

```
* service[postfix] action enable

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `enable` on resource 'service[postfix]'
    ================================================================================

    TypeError
    ---------
    no implicit conversion of false into Array

ERROR: service[postfix] (base::setup_mail line 54) had an error: TypeError: no implicit conversion of false into Array
```

This has started occurring recently, this recipe had been working before without any issues, and the error is not really making sense to me. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The issue was because the chef-client being installed during bootstrap was v12, but my server was still v11, when I downgraded the chef-client to v11 the chef-run went through without a problem

thanks for everyone's help

Comment: I would normally expect a stack trace included here. Is this the whole error?

Comment: Also, could you share your OS distro and version with us? Chef has different provider implementations for different distros and versions of Linux.

Comment: Hi thanks for the efforts but after playing around a bit more, I found out that the issue was because my chef-client was v12 and chef-server was running v11, when I downgraded the chef-client to v11 the chef-run went through without a problem